# Windows Phone Emulator Application Development Error

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am encountering an error on my emulator.

I've been developing an application for windows phone, it used to run okay and there was no error.

Recently, i upgraded my visual studio, now my project cannot be loaded. So I  tried reinstalling my visual studio.

After reinstalling, an Application Development Error occured. I've looked for a solution but have been unable to find one.

During my search, I found out that my emulator didn't work properly. It was starting up, but after 13 seconds it reboots again and starts up again, this loop keeps going for several minutes. After that my visual studio gives me an error.

This led me to believe that the error was caused by a virtual hard disk issue, so I choose the virtual hard disk from MicrosoftSDKs/Windows Phone/Emulation/Images/Flash.VHD and it is running now.

But after I configure my settings of the emulator to change its virtual hard disk to Flash.VHD, It doesn't work at all. It keeps restarting over and over again.

I have been trying to solve this error for 4 days.

Comment: Have you tried opening Hyper-V Manager and deleting your emulator VMs? If they don't exist, Visual Studio will recreate them automatically for you.

Comment: I've done that, but still doesn't work. and then I go to option repairing my "VS" then it's working. :) Thanks a lot.